# Docker images and containers change when docker desktop is running on linux

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-20.04, docker-desktop

When docker desktop is running on linux, I see a different set of containers and images compared to when it is not running. That is, when I run `docker images` in the terminal, the output depends on whether docker desktop is running or not. After I 'quit docker desktop', the original behavior is restored.

I note the following changes:

| docker desktop is off | docker desktop is running |
| --- | --- |
| images 'a, b, c' | shows images 'd, e, f' |
| containers 'aa, bb, cc' | containers 'dd, ee, ff' |
| non colored cli output | pretty colored cli output |

My suspicion is that docker desktop kills a running docker service and starts a fresh one whose images and containers are located elsewhere on my filesystem. Then after quitting, the original service is restored. I'd like this behavior to change, such that the images and containers I'm working on are always the same, regardless of whether docker desktop is running or not.

I'm looking for some feedback on how to start debugging this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker only runs natively on Linux. Docker Desktop is the "hack" that allows running docker on other platforms (MacOS, Windows, etc). Docker Desktop actually starts a Linux VM and runs docker inside that VM. It then takes care of mapping ports and volumes so that it appears to the end user that docker is "running directly on host".

The beauty of running Docker on linux is that it runs natively and you don't need extra hacks and tricks. So why you would use Docker Desktop on Ubuntu.... beats me :) However, the explanation of why you see different results is becuase you see different docker processes running on different machines: one on the host and one on a VM.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question :) I like live dashboard with images and containers, which is why I use it. I thought the docker desktop was just a GUI front-end to my native installation. Maybe I should get rid of it again.

Comment: @SamDeMeyer If you like "that stuff" you should check [Portainer](https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/portainer-ce). You  probably have other tools as well. They connect directly to the docker daemon and you see that because it is part of the installation procedure. good luck!